# Microsoft's CodeView format specs

Tags: debugging, specifications, msdn, code-view

I've been looking for a Microsoft document from the 1990's called *CodeView Symbolic Debug Information Specification*. It's referenced by Microsoft in their [PE/COFF spec](http://elfz.laacz.lv/ms_exe_spec.html#L61). Information about this document is sparse, and [every lead](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=beedf1a58b456416fab309d51d0ccc2a&action=printpage%3Btopic=4718.0) I come across ends in a 404. Unfortunately I don't have any old MSDN CD's, which seemed to end the search for a few people.

Does anyone have a copy, or know where I could find any related specs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The one Matt Pietrek linked to, but which is not available at the original address anymore.](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/pierrelib/exec_formats/MS_Symbol_Type_v1.0.pdf) - Note that this is one of the official CodeView 4 specifications, it doesn't cover CodeView 5 format.

**Update:** I found a copy of the "CV4 Symbolic Debug Information Specification" document. It is revision 4, dated December 1, 1995. Compared to the document linked above it has additional chapter "8. The TypeServer API" and appendix with revision history, the rest is mostly the same. All the references to "Microsoft CodeView" were replaced with "Mirosoft symbol and type". The original specification is marked as Microsoft Confidential, so I will not release it, but it offers no benefit over the document linked above.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Since you mentioned it, would you also happen to know where I could get the specs for CodeView 5?

Comment: @zildjohn01 There was a document called "Visual C++ 5.0 Symbolic Debug Information Specification" which describes CodeView 5 format, unfortunately I don't have a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a copy of the "Visual C++ 5.0 Symbolic Debug Information Specification" document. You need to download the "MSDN Library October 2001" from MSDN Subscriber Downloads. After installing it, you'll find it under "Specifications - Visual C++ 5.0 Symbolic Debug Information Specification".

If you don't want to install the library at all, you'll find the "specs.chi" file on the first disc and the "specs.chm" file on the second disc. Copy those out and you'll be able to read the document without installing the library.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/read.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=c++.windows.32-bits&artnum=912), no one ever put it online...

I think [this book](http://mihai.christodorescu.org/docs/PECOFF60.doc) replaced it... It should be backwards compatible, though.

Comment: Sorry, that .doc is the same file as the PE/COFF spec I linked to in my question.

Comment: Same doc, different link and format. It's the version that keeps popping over everywhere.

Comment: More links the better; old content has a tendancy to vanish. Watcom has one provide (http://www.openwatcom.org/ftp/devel/docs/CodeView.pdf)