# Can I generate a .RSM file myself for the Delphi Debugger to use?

Tags: delphi, debugging

I wish to debug executables for which I have no code, using the Delphi Debugger.

WinDBG and other debuggers are no option in this case, as the given executables all call into my DLL, for which I *do* have code, obviously. My ultimate goal is, to see a stack-trace right down into the functions of the running executable.

I do have symbol-information for these executables, so I was hoping I could write my own .RSM files for this purpose. Will this work? Will the Delphi debugger pick up any .RSM file that it can find? And would that mean that other debug-information should be left out?

Do note that there are lots of executables that I need to debug, and for all of them I detect the symbols inside them myself, using a moderately advanced function-detection algorithm. So my main problem mainly is how to write .RSM files. For this I have to know the structure of the .RSM file-format. Is there documentation or example code available somewhere that shows me how to create such a file?

Any help is appreciated!

PS: Might you be wondering why I'm doing all this : It's all related to [Dxbx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dxbx/) - an open-source Xbox1 emulator. See sourceforce for details. New members are welcome!

Comment: RSM files are for Remote Debugging.  If you have symbol files, are you asking how to convert these files into a format that Delphi can use?  What format is your original symbols in?  As I have see tools to convert before.  Which version of Delphi?

Comment: @Robert Love : I have the symbols in memory (just a list of addresses with names, really) - I just need to write them out somehow, in the hope the debugger loads em back in. All I want is to see my detected symbols appear in the Delphi stacktrace window. Does the .RSM format change between Delphi versions? In that case, my order of preference is : D2007, D2010, D2009, D2006, D2005, D7, D5.

Answer (score 1):

I found a page that says the format is similar to CodeView (www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Debugging_Format_Interoperability)

There is a link to this reference at [Microsoft's CodeView format specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418660/microsofts-codeview-format-specs)

I doubt this fully answers your question, but maybe it will get you a little further?

Comment: I assume this is as close to an answer as I'll ever get ;-) Thanks for your attention.